# How to solve ERROR - Expected boolean value (or no value) following argument: --train

Tags: tensorflow, darkflow

I'm training a model to use for object detection using YOLO-darkflow but i get this error. How can  i solve it.

```
2020-01-24 11:37:37.478285: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
2020-01-24 11:37:37.486159: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
WARNING:tensorflow:
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:15: The name tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.RMSPropOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:16: The name tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdadeltaOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:17: The name tf.train.AdagradOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:18: The name tf.train.AdagradDAOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdagradDAOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:19: The name tf.train.MomentumOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.MomentumOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:20: The name tf.train.AdamOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:21: The name tf.train.FtrlOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.FtrlOptimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From D:\TensorFlow\darkflow-master\darkflow\net\build.py:22: The name tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer instead.


ERROR - Expected boolean value (or no value) following argument: --train
```

The command i'm using to train is:`python flow --model cfg/tiny-yolo-voc-1c.cfg --load bin/yolov2-tiny.weights --train train/Annotations --dataset train/Images --epoch 1000`. What am i missing or doing wrong. I.m using tensorflow==1.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't pass the annotations into the training parameter, try reformating the command to look more like this:

```
python flow --model Training\yolo_StopSignTest.cfg --labels Training\Labels.txt --train --trainer adam --dataset "Training\Images\\" --annotation "Training\Annotations\\"
```

Comment: It runs then brings an error.  Dataset size 0. And stops. Returns an error ZeroDivisionError